# Trying to delete duplicate workspace

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation, workspace

I've got a hosted SP2007 environment. I don't know much about this site but I was asked to delete a duplication in the workspace. I'm not sure how. [This i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDhFw.jpg)s what I'm looking at. There are two dates with 10/25/2013, I need to remove one of those, not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual solution: this list is a hidden list within the workspace that has permissions locked down hard. Crashed my SPD multiple times and corrupted my test meeting workspace as I tried to mess with it. [Here is one solution through Visual Studio](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/cant-remove-a-meeting-workspace-instance).

You might have an easier time adding JQuery and some JavaScript to your page and just hiding the problematic meeting instance.

Original, incorrect text: *You need to go into the Calendar, see if there are two meetings on the 15th, and delete one of them. If that's a recurring meeting, then you likely only have 1 workspace for the set. If that's the case, don't delete the workspace, only the calendar item! Verify by going to All Site Content and looking at what workspaces are listed.*

Comment: When I go into the calendar. There are 4 events on that date. # of them are reoccurring and assigned a workspace. There are no duplicates however.

Comment: In All Site Content, do you see duplicate workspaces? Perhaps the calendar events are covering each other up; when you switch to "All Events" view, are there still only 4 events on the 15th?

Comment: This is what I see : http://imgur.com/a/Z7PT7
  all the events on that day are assigned to a different work group.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent screenshots. I've done some experimenting and have an actual solution. I'm updating my above post.

Comment: I can easily hide it using JQuery. Might be what I end up doing since I dont like doing Visual studio

Comment: Thank's for being patient with my twice-wrong "answers". If you get a JavaScript solution, would you mind posting it as an answer to your question, for posterity?

Comment: Yea no problem, ill look into it tomorrow. It will likely just be something that grabs that element and sets the display to none. I'll post when I write it.